# moving in the wrong direction

Tags: mathematics, geometry

**Solution**:

To move a unit forward:

```
forward = Quaternion(0,0,0,1)
rotation.normalize() # ocassionally
...
pos += ((rotation * forward) * rotation.conjugated()).xyz().normalized() * speed
```

I think the trouble stemmed from how the Euclid math library was doing Quaternion*Vector3 multiplication, although I can't see it.

---

I have a vec3 position, a quaternion for rotation and a speed.

I compute the player position like this:

```
rot *= Quaternion().rotate_euler(0.,roll_speed,pitch_speed)
rot.normalize()
pos += rot.conjugated() * Vector3(0.,0.,-speed)
```

However, printing the pos to console, I can see that I only ever seem to travel on the x-axis.

When I draw the scene using the `rot` quaternion to rotate my camera, it shows a proper orientation.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's an example:

- You start off with rotation being an identity quaternion: w=1,x=0,y=0,z=0
- You move forward; the code correctly decrements the Z
- You then pitch right over to face the other way; if you spin only 175deg it'll go in right direction; you have to spin past 180deg.  It doesn't matter which direction you spin in, up or down, though
- Your quaternion can then be something like: w=0.1,x=0.1,y=0,z=0
- And moving forward, you actually move backward?!

(I am using the [euclid](http://pyeuclid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/euclid.py) Python module, but its the same as every other conjulate)

**The code** can be tried online at http://williame.github.com/ludum_dare_24_evolution/
The only key that adjusts the speed is W and S.  The arrow keys only adjust the pitch/roll.

At first you can fly ok, but after a bit of weaving around you end up getting sucked towards one of the sides.  The code is https://github.com/williame/ludum_dare_24_evolution/blob/cbacf61a7159d2c83a2187af5f2015b2dde28687/tiny1web.py#L102

Comment: What are you expecting. Multiplying two vectors is multiplying its components. So [6, 7, 8] * [0, 0, 1] = [0, 0, 8].

Comment: yes, but rot is a quaternion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotation of the direction-vector using the quaternion is wrong, it must be:

```
    Pout = q * Pin * conj(q)

    Pin  -> input vector
    q    -> quaternion
    Pout -> rotated output vector
```

Details can be found here: [Transformations using Quaternions](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/transforms/index.htm)

Code correction:

```
    pos += rot * Vector3(0.,0.,-speed) * rot.conjugated()
```

**Note:** If the movement is still wrong, then `roll_speed` and `pitch_speed` are most likely absolute values, rather than the relative orientation change in this frame, then the first line would have to be:

```
    rot = Quaternion().rotate_euler(0.,roll_speed,pitch_speed)
```

Comment: I can quat*vec3 but not vec3*quat - this is just how the libary is.  So can you clarify if you mean (r*v)*conj(r) or conj(r)*(r*v)?  (roll/pitch/speeds are deltas for this 'tick')  (I still have problems; it flies around a bit but after a while it stops flying, or starts moving when speed is 0.  I begin to suspect problems with my rot not being normalised or something?

Comment: It is: (q*v)*q' .. q*v should return a quaternion, so the second operation should not be vec3*quat, but quat*quat

Comment: I tried also (q*Quat(0,0,0,-1)*conj(q)).xyz.normalized() * client.speed too.  It all mostly works.  And then, after quite a bit of flying around, you find yourself flying towards some side regardless of where you are pointing.

Comment: The formula in your last comment is simply wrong, you need the one from my post and in the link I gave you.

Comment: [Here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/transforms/index.htm#code) is the code example for the transformation

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you've taken to lead me to the answer.  I've posted a link to the code in the question.  I've tried all variations of your code, and of course the bug must be in my code somewhere. But its hard to understand how the roll can become movement etc. :(

Comment: @Will Just post the relevant code here as an edit in your question

Comment: The link is straight to the appropriate code, which is a copy of your linked code

Comment: @Will ok then, next step for you is debugging, print out all relevant values for each moving step to see where it goes wrong

Comment: (Yeah I had started with printf debugging and I wouldn't know what a valid quat printed, let alone the point at which it gets corrupted; I'm raking my brains regards normalisation and such)

Comment: @Will set roll_speed and pitch_speed hardcoded to zero and print the first 3 frames or so as edit into your question, I'll have a look at the values

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4634/discussion-between-maik-semder-and-will)